# Angular equivalent of Radio Button Change Event

Tags: angularjs

In jQuery I would do something like:

```
$( ".radio-buttons" ).change(function() {
 ..
});
```

How would I do the same in Angular JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to monitor a radio button changes ,

First is to use **ng-change along with the radio button**,

```
</label><input type="radio" ng-model="radioValue" ng-change="invokeChangeFunction()" />Yes</label>
```

In controller ,

```
$scope.invokeChangeFunction = function() {
   console.log($scope.value);
}
```

Second method is using **$watch for ng-model**,

```
$scope.$watch('radioValue', function(value) {
       console.log(value);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="change()">
```

In controller

```
 $scope.change=function(){
    //your logic
    }
```